# Full Oracle Apex page to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, pdf, oracle-apex

I'm trying to generate a PDF document from an APEX page, using built-in charts, rich text editors, etc.

How would I go about capturing it? I've been searching around trying different client-side javascript libraries, such as jsPDF and html2canvas, but they have rendering issues with APEX.

I am aware that interactive reports have the ability to be exported as a PDF. I want this feature for other region types.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: what sort of rendering issues do you face with those libraries?
Are they screenshotting the page, then generating PDF from that?

Comment: Yes, they are rendering a PDF from the client. The charts are either zoomed in funny or there are thousands of blank pages.

Comment: Interesting, that's all I would have suggested. Printing web pages is a pain, regardless of the tech that generated it. Probably depends on the APEX version too, and the charting library, and how you applied the JS libraries...